# Graphic of the week

Tags: feature-request

One thing I've seen in the photography community, and I think this site would really benefit from, is some kind of a design of the week. Specify a size, and let people show off their talent to the whole group. Vote on everyone's favorite over the course of the week, and post the wining graphic for the next week.

Comment: Do you have a link to the same _feature_ from the photography community you're talking about? Just to see if it's relevant in this SE case. To downvoter, any comment? :)

Comment: An example of a weekly voting thread is at this link: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/571/weekly-featured-image-for-january-10-2011 .

Answer (score 4):

While I think the photo of the week is great, I think it cannot be *directly* copied over here.

Something longer and bigger like *design of the month* or *design for the fortnight* would suite this site better and users could redesign **the whole `graphicdesign.stackexchange` site**. OK, "whole site" is rather exaggerated, but now that I got your attention, it could be just **some elements and some colour codes** (e.g. see what impact only the change of background image has in Twitter).

Pros:

- Reflects the community, as designs are constantly in-fashion and out-of-fashion at the same time
- Different
- Inspiring
- Neat

Cons:

- Technical implementation

  - File uploads
  - File sizes
  - User rights
- Effects on usability

  - Though community moderation probably works this out
- Has to be done exclusively for this site

  - E.g. Photo of the week could be (almost) any photo in your archives resized and cropped, webdesign probably not
- Web biased

  - I think there are print designers and the like in the community too
- Needs more work
- Will it get enough attention?

Comment: To answer your Cons : Technical impletementation isn't a problem since it works on _photo_. Hosted elsewhere and shown as on _photo_ or _so_. As this site isn't only _webdesign_ but _graphic design_, everyone can participate, print and web. website can definitely be screenshoted, resized and be here. As for the attention, I really hope it would :)

Comment: Both of your points are true, but my answer was wrong: after I read your comment I realized I forgot to mention what I meant with "whole site" which made my answer a bit ambiguous. I've edited my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at it as a meta-topic, I think it is a neat idea to encourage the community to recheck the meta section.

If you want this for the main site, I think you are looking at this wrong way for a site that was made for Question and Answers. There is already a strong Dribble.com community for displays. Instead (at least for the section of the community labelled programmers who design), it would be good to have a type of question in which one can objectively tell a person what can be fixed in their design. Not necessarily a " How do I do this in Photoshop/Paper/Gimp/Illustrator " but more like

I attempted to perform this action/set of actions on my design here are the steps/tools I used to make this work. What fix to my workflow or new set can I use to get the result I am looking for (brush strokes/ increasing hardness/ changing swatches) ? Thus instead of design of the week, everyone down to amateurs can have a stab at attempting work. This could get subjective so maybe someone with experience can define the line there.

Comment: In the photo.stackexchange the weekly photo is more part of the website layout than a work display. The voting is indeed done in the meta. See last week's topic here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/560/weekly-featured-image-for-january-3-2011 and the result on the front page here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/