# "Logo of the week" Contest

Tags: feature-request

Related question: [Graphic of the Week](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/graphic-of-the-week). Also related question that gave origin to this one: [Openly Editable Site Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/openly-editable-site-design).

We have been considering the idea of a '**Logo of the Week** (or month)', like Photography's [Weekly Featured Photo](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest). This logo, voted by the community in meta, would be the GD.SE logo for a week, month, or whatever we choose.

To SE: Is this possible if we are still in Beta?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible at all, but we will certainly look into it when the site is graduating. In the meantime feel free to toss around ideas for how you guys might like it to work.

Comment: i like this idea

Comment: we could probably do trend of the month also..to highlight new trends that are emerging and seem to be promising.

Comment: Now that the GD.SE community is close to going out of beta, can this idea be reconsidered?

Comment: @BartArondson I think it would be too difficult to implement now that Stephane is actually working on the design as a whole. He is probably preparing everything for the graduation, we are so close!

Comment: True, maybe it's better to wait until the site is graduated so it's easier to see where a potential contest would fit in.

Answer (score 6):

I think the idea of **Logo of the Week** would be really cool.

Thinking about it a little further, what if we would do a **Logo of the Week** (or month to help develop thorough concepts) for the Graphic Design Stack Exchange site? The winner would be the GDSE logo for the month.

Entries would be images posted as answers and the one with the most votes by the end of the deadline would win.

Sort of like how [Google](http://www.google.com/doodles/finder/2013/All%20doodles) does their logo differently for holidays and notable historic days.

Comment: This is was I was thinking too, just edited my question because it wasn't very clear :)

Answer (score 6):

I think every week would be way too often - it works for photography because photographers can submit photos they had taken anyway for other reasons, whereas it sounds like we're asking people to sit down and make a design purely for this contest on this site each time, which is very different.

I like the idea though. Maybe every three weeks or every month, with a different theme, concept or limitation each time - something that makes it a very different type of interesting challenge each time it comes around.

Something unusual and fun so people can use it as a way to use techniques or styles they'd never use in their day jobs, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

I think specifying "logo" is too narrow. Not everyone creates a logo every week. And surely a site dedicated to Graphic Design doesn't want to appear to be crowd-sourcing.

I'd think a "project" or "design" of the week may be better. It allows for wider range of things and doesn't funnel submissions to only logos.

.... unless, you were thinking of each week the GD.SE logo is to be redesigned.

Comment: Yes, I was actually thinking of the DG.SE logo redesign (maybe not entirely, leaving a base and working around that)

Comment: Yes changing the actual GD.SE logo as a redesign by the community was the type of thing I had in mind.